# Click on list item in conditionally activated list doesn´t trigger

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a dropdown selection menu which consists of a list which is only activated when i click on a button. I want to change the selected value when one of the list items is clicked.
But `(click)="subject_select(subject)"` doesn´t get triggered. I think that the list is disabled before the click event can do anything. That is because when i remove the `(focusout)="toggleSelectionMenu()"` the selection works but i want the list to disappear when the user clicks outside of the button.

The `[@selectionMenuInOut]` animation is set to 100ms, so that shouldn´t be the problem.

```
<div>
<button type="button"
    (click)="toggleSelectionMenu()" (focusout)="toggleSelectionMenu()">
    <span> {{ selected }} </span>
</button>
<ul
    tabindex="-1" *ngIf="selectionMenu==true" [@selectionMenuInOut]>
    <li (click)="subject_select(subject)" *ngFor="let subject of subjects">
        <span>{{ subject }}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

My typescript functions are:

```
  selectionMenu: boolean = false;
  subjects = ['Website errors', 'Need support', 'Pizza!'];
  selected: string = 'Choose subject of the request';
  subject_select(subject: string) {
    this.selected = subject;
  }

  toggleSelectionMenu() {
    this.selectionMenu = !this.selectionMenu;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what happens when clicking a list element:

1. The `onmousedown` event fires
2. The `focusout` event on the toggle button fires
3. The list is being removed from the DOM
4. The `onmouseup` event doesn't fire because the element doesn't exist anymore, so the `click` event doesn't fire

In my opinion it's a bad idea to implement the outside click by using the `focusout` event on the toggle button. Not only it causes this bug, it also makes the element not accessible by keyboard. See this question for alternatives: [How to detect click outside of an element in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51150422/how-to-detect-click-outside-of-an-element-in-angular)