# Angular 17 clickOutside directive based on HostListener does not work

Tags: angular17

I'm testing HostListener decorator in my project followed Angular materials, supported by YT videos but I'm struggle get expected result means, closing hamburger menu clicking outside of the menu.
Below is code to my clickOutsideDirective. I checked the below via various other sources and it seems correctly coded

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter, HostListener, Output,  } from '@angular/core';


@Directive({
  selector: '[clickOutside]',
  standalone: true
})

export class ClickOutsideDirective {
 @Output() clickOutside = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  @HostListener ('document:click', ['$event.target'])
  public onClick(targetElement: HTMLElement): void{
    const clickedInside = this.elementRef.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);
    if (!clickedInside){
      this.clickOutside.emit();
    }
  }

}
```

Below my HTML code from main-nav.component.html explain how I installed clickOutsideDirective and open menu function.

```
<header >
  <div class="main" clickOutside (clickOutside)="clickOutside()">
      <nav class="menu">
          <div class="mobile_menu" (click)="toggleMenu()">
              <img src="assets/hmbr_icon.png" alt="hamburger menu" class="hmbr_icon" >
              <i class="{{mobile_icon}}"></i>
          </div>
          <ul class="desktop_menu" [class.mobile_menu]="isMenuOpened" >
              <li  >menuItem1</li>
              <li  >menuItem2</li>
              <li  >menuItem3</li> 
              <li  >menuItem4</li>
              <li  >menuItem5</li>
          </ul>

      </nav>
      <div class="logo_cnt">
      <a href="#"><img src="assets/logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="getUser">Hello Chris!</div>
  </div>
</header>
```

The hamburger menu opens and closes rules I coded in main-nav.component.ts as per below and It works. Hamburger menu is open after clicking on icon but closes only after clicking on the icon which suggest that clickOutsideDirective does not work,

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main-nav',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './main-nav.component.html',
  styleUrl: './main-nav.component.css'
})
export class MainNavComponent {
  isMenuOpened: boolean = false;
  mobile_icon:string='hmbr_icon'


  toggleMenu(): void{
    this.isMenuOpened = !this.isMenuOpened;
    this.mobile_icon = this.isMenuOpened ? 'x_icon' : 'hmbr_icon';
  }

  clickOutside(): void{
    this.isMenuOpened = false;
  }

}
```

I verified written code through various fora and YT videos, I change declaration of clickOutsideDirective in parent div. I'm also getting info about problem in terminal which indicate that const directive expects 1 argument but gets 0 with thr reference point to the new ElementRef in click-outside.directive.ts
I'm not sure what should I add to the code to fix this problem and whether after fixing directive will work correctly.

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51150422/how-to-detect-click-outside-of-an-element-in-angular